# JAVA: Type parameter hiding class type

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, types, covariance

I have this

```
abstract class Operand {
    public abstract <T extends Operand> Operand operation(Operator operator, T operand);
}
abstract class Numeric extends Operand {
}
class Integer extends Numeric 
    @Override
    public <Integer> Operand operation(Operator operator, Integer operand) {//problem
    }
}
```

How can I solve this situation?
I don't want to use generics in the class Operand (so I have Operand) because I need Operand to be a single type. Inside the Integer's method I need to call the constructor (new Integer(arg)), a solution could be to call that method in some other way.
Solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with **overloaded method**

```
abstract class Operand {
    public abstract <T extends Operand> Operand operation(Operator operator, T operand);
}

abstract class Numeric<T extends Numeric<T>> extends Operand {
    public abstract Operand operation(Operator operator, T operand);
}

class Integer extends Numeric<Integer> {

    @Override
    public Operand operation(Operator operator, Integer operand) {
        // add your Integer specific code here
        return null; // replace null with actual returned value
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends Operand> Operand operation(Operator operator, T operand) {
        // simply call to overridden Integer specific method
        // no harm to downcast it here
        return operation(operator, (Integer) operand); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your method declaration in `Operand`, which is `<T extends Operand>`, you must match that "contract" with your implementation -

```
class Integer extends Numeric {
  @Override
  public <T extends Operand> Operand operation(Operator operator, T operand) {
    // Like this....
  }
}
```

Comment: But the second argument of Integer.operation is always Integer, it must not be any other type.

Comment: @biowep Then you should make the Numeric and Operand classes generic, as is you have an abstract generic method. And you must implement it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you want something like this:

```
abstract class Operand<T, U> {
    public abstract T operation(Operator operator, U operand);
}
abstract class Numeric<T, U> extends Operand<T, U> {
}
class Integer extends Numeric<Integer, Integer>
    @Override
    public Integer operation(Operator operator, Integer operand) {
    }
}
```